# Hibernate class - Read from one view(table), and write to another

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I need to connect to a DB that has for each entity, a view for reading and a view for writing. This is done to control the update process of values by enforcing business rules.

From what I've read in the hibernate documentation, every class is mapped to a single view(table).

Is it possible in hibernate to define that the getters look at one view, and the setters on another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"You can't do that". Use following steps
Eg: You have two tables say A, B

Create Mapper for both classes and use setters of B to set the values that are featched by getters of A.